# how to solve Subquery returns more than 1 row error in multiple selection

Tags: mysql

I have a very long MYSQL query which select a total number from four tables, but one of subqueries return more than one row and cause an error.
this is my query:

```
select created,  
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from capitals group by created )  as capital,

    (select coalesce(sum(incoming), 0) - coalesce(sum(outgoing), 0) from transactions where currency = 'دالر') +
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from transactions where incoming != 0 ) -
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from transactions where outgoing != 0 ) as total_transaction,

    (select coalesce(sum(incoming), 0) - coalesce(sum(outgoing), 0) from temporary_clients where currency = 'دالر') +
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from temporary_clients where incoming != 0 ) -
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from temporary_clients where outgoing != 0 ) as total_temp_client,

    (select coalesce(sum(outgoing), 0) - coalesce(sum(incoming), 0) from money_transmission where currency = 'دالر') +
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from money_transmission where outgoing != 0 ) -
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from money_transmission where incoming != 0 ) as total_transmission,

    (select coalesce(total_transaction + total_temp_client + total_transmission, 0)) as total,

    (select capital - abs(coalesce(total_transaction + total_temp_client + total_transmission, 0))) as result
    from capitals group by created
```

in this query the first selection `created` returns more than one value and the first subquery which end with `as capital` also return more than one value.
this query should return a result of calculation of capital with total of other three tables for each date in database.
I check many questions that has the same error and all of them used `IN` or `inner join` in `where` clause but i think my case is different and I don't know what to do.
please help me if you have any idea how can I solve this problem.
thank you :)

Comment: The error message is clear: One or more of the subqueries is returning more than one record.  You are in the best position to clean up the logic and correct this.

Comment: as I mention in my question the first subquery return more than one record and I know this, but it has to be like this because I need to subtract capital of each day from total of all other tables and receive a single value for each day.

Comment: Then your query does not make logical sense because you can't do scalar addition and subtraction with sets of values.  Show us some sample table data along with your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
select created,c.sum_dollars

    (select coalesce(sum(incoming), 0) - coalesce(sum(outgoing), 0) from transactions where currency = 'دالر') +
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from transactions where incoming != 0 ) -
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from transactions where outgoing != 0 ) as total_transaction,

    (select coalesce(sum(incoming), 0) - coalesce(sum(outgoing), 0) from temporary_clients where currency = 'دالر') +
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from temporary_clients where incoming != 0 ) -
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from temporary_clients where outgoing != 0 ) as total_temp_client,

    (select coalesce(sum(outgoing), 0) - coalesce(sum(incoming), 0) from money_transmission where currency = 'دالر') +
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from money_transmission where outgoing != 0 ) -
    (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) from money_transmission where incoming != 0 ) as total_transmission,

    (select coalesce(total_transaction + total_temp_client + total_transmission, 0)) as total,

    (select capital - abs(coalesce(total_transaction + total_temp_client + total_transmission, 0))) as result
    from capitals
 JOIN (select coalesce(sum(equal_to_dollar), 0) as sum_dollars, created from capitals group by   created )  c ON capitals.created = c.created
 group by created
```

I can't really test cause I don't know you database schema. You should JOIN those result sets anyway.

Comment: thank you very much it is working by a little changes